# Tests for HTML5 tags, events, and attributes support

Tags: javascript, browser, html

Does anyone have a foolproof way to test for the existence of an HTML5 tag, events, or attribute?  What I would essentially like to do is browser test one or more of these.  I am well aware of projects like modernizr, however I need something very specific.

For example, Javascript which provided capability for these mocked functions would be ideal:

```
bool IsHTML5TagSupported( tag )
bool IsHTML5EventSupported( event )
bool IsHTML5AttributeSupported( attribute );
```

UPDATE: Some good reference here http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/everything.html, but by no means complete coverage of tags such as article, nav, header, etc. as well as events and all attributes.

Comment: Why not look and see how modernizr does its detection? :)

Comment: Those functions look like Java... which I don't consider to be ideal ;) Otherwise +1 for Nick.

Comment: @Ivo: No, they don't.  Java doesn't have a `bool` keyword or `'` strings.  You mean to say that it should be `isHTML5...`, or `html5.supportsAttribute(...)`

Comment: Guys, these are mock language agnostic signatures for discussion purposes.  Modernizr does not have support for these features.

Comment: @SLaks It's 3am here, everything starts looking like Java if you need a big cup of coffee... yes they should start with a lowercase letter I guess.

Comment: @Nick It doesn't do these things fully.

Comment: Can you define "Supported"? For example, is the hgroup element only "supported" if the browser correctly selects the appropriate contained heading element to expose as the heading to the O/S's accessibility API? If not, what? and how do you get the writers of such API's to agree with you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/modernizr.js) has a function for `isEventSupported` and testing for attributes is quite straightforward (have a look at the first test in `function webforms()` in the modernizr code).

When it comes to supporting tags 'such as article, nav, header, etc' I doubt you really need to test for that.  If we leave aside IE for the moment, the difference between a browser which supports `article` and a browser which doesn't is that the former will provide some default CSS for the element.  Since you can just provide your own CSS (`display: block;` plus whatever styles you were going to provide anyway) it's hard to see where you might need to detect the support.

If you're still keen to test for support for these elements you can just look for those default styles, for example:

```
function IsHTML5TagSupported(tag) {
    var t = document.createElement(tag);
    document.body.appendChild(t);
    var ret;
    if (window.getComputedStyle) ret = window.getComputedStyle(t, null).getPropertyValue("display") == 'block';
    if (t.currentStyle) ret = t.currentStyle.display == 'block';
    document.body.removeChild(t);
    return ret;
}

window.alert(IsHTML5TagSupported('article'));
```

You need to actually append the element for the browser to compute the styles, and I've added the `currentStyle` line for IE even though we can be sure it doesn't support it.  Obviously this particular approach is only going to work for elements that are supposed to be block level, but you could extend it to look at a different property for the rest.  Of course, calling `document.createElement('article')` will cause IE to apply user styles to subsequent `article` elements and having `article { display: block; }` in your stylesheet will cause all browsers to 'support' the `article` element.

Perhaps a more interesting thing to test for is compliance with the [HTML5 parsing algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/parsing.html#parsing), as that may have some impact on the DOM tree you are dealing with in script and whether you'll be able to do things like [insert inline SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_Parser).  Have a look at the `testParsing` function in the source code of [The HTML5 Test](http://html5test.com/) for that.

Comment: Great feedback.  I'm going to dig into this deeper.